# Knife Tool not working in a scene

Tags: modeling, knife-tool

Strange thing: The knife tool does not work in one scene (meaning I am not able to click anything, the knife just hovers over the mesh). But... it works fine if I am opening another scene and apply it there. Coming back to the scene in question once again nothing. Ideas? I am using Blender 2.83.4